# Why does my table say “No data available” instead of zero?

Tags: r

I need to create multiple new data frames based on different filters that contain two variable counts “d” & “e” based of the values in columns “a”, “b” and “c”. I have created a function for this that works as long as at least one column has a value. However, sometimes certain groups will have no answer for a, b or c. I want both d and e to both return zero in the columns when this happens but instead it says “No data available in table”. I’ve added my code below.

```
f_calculate_net = function(data) 
{ data %>% mutate(a = ifelse("a" %in% colnames(data), a, 0)) %>% 
mutate(b = ifelse("b" %in% colnames(data), b, 0)) %>% 
mutate(c = ifelse("c" %in% colnames(data), c, 0)) %>% 
mutate(d = ifelse(a + b + c == 0, 0, ((a/(a+b))*c)+a)) %>% 
mutate(e = ifelse(a + b + c == 0, 0, ((b/(a+b))*c)+b)) %>% 
select(d,e) }
```

A sample of the dataframe is

| wt | beet | ilo | age | country | ine | sex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 647 | a | 3 | 19 | 1 | 24 | 1 |
| 875 | b | 3 | 18 | 1 | 27 | 2 |
| 647 | c | 1 | 24 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 875 | b | 3 | 20 | 1 | 27 | 2 |
| 435 | b | 2 | 66 | 4 | 31 | 1 |
| 643 | a | 1 | 32 | 3 | 5 | 1 |
| 496 | b | 2 | 47 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 511 | c | 2 | 23 | 4 | 2 | 1 |
| 774 | a | 2 | 37 | 5 | 5 | 1 |
| 550 | b | 1 | 24 | 1 | 1 | 2 |

I take the main dataset and then apply a filter and count the number responses of the variable beet

```
data2 <- df_beet %>% filter(age == 18 & sex == 1 & ilo == 2) %>% 
count(beet, wt = wt) %>%
pivot_wider(names_from = beet, values from = n) %>%
f_calculate_net()
```

There are no results and the resulting dataframe shows the columns d and e but it doesn’t show zeros and instead shows “no data available”

Comment: Perhaps ironically I can say "we have no data available" here in the question as well. Can you please make this question reproducible by adding some sample data? It's usually best to use `dput(head(x,10))` (or some number of rows), since the use of `dput` provides an easy and unambiguous dataset representative of what you really need.

Comment: I’be added a table with a small sample of my dataframe and the code that the function is used in

Answer (score 1):

When a and b are zero a/b is NAN. If you want this case to be zero, try change a + b + c == 0  to  (a + b) == 0

Based on Allan's explanation and comment, another possibility is to make a logical vector of the same length as the number of rows:

```
f_calculate_net = function(data) 
{ data %>%
    mutate(a = ifelse(rep("a" %in% colnames(data), nrow(data)), a, 0)) %>% 
    mutate(b = ifelse(rep("b" %in% colnames(data), nrow(data)), b, 0)) %>% 
    mutate(c = ifelse(rep("c" %in% colnames(data), nrow(data)), c, 0)) %>% 
    mutate(d = ifelse(a + b  == 0, 0, ((a/(a+b))*c)+a)) %>% 
    mutate(e = ifelse(a + b  == 0, 0, ((b/(a+b))*c)+b)) %>% 
    select(d,e) }
```

Comment: This is right, but doesn't fix the problem of the first 3 `ifelse` statements rewriting the existing columns with the first entry of each column.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem here is in the way you are using `ifelse`. The expression `"a" %in% colnames(data)` always returns a length-1 logical vector (either `TRUE` or `FALSE`). So the output of the expression `ifelse("a" %in% colnames(data), a, 0)` will also be of length 1. It will return either *the first element* of `a` or a single 0. Since this is inside a `mutate` call, `a` will either be overwritten by the first element of `a`, or will be created as a column of zeros. Instead of `ifelse` you should use

```r
if(!"a" %in% colnames(data)) data$a <- 0
```

And the same for columns `b` and `c`.

You will sometimes still get a `NaN` entry in columns `d` and `e` here if both `a` and `b` are 0, but `c` isn't, since your expression `((a/(a+b))*c)+a)` divides by the sum of `a` and `b`. You should only check whether `a + b == 0`, since in that case you should return a `0`

So the fixed function would be something like:

```r
f_calculate_net = function(data) { 
  
  if(!"a" %in% colnames(data)) data$a <- 0
  if(!"b" %in% colnames(data)) data$b <- 0
  if(!"c" %in% colnames(data)) data$c <- 0
  
  data %>% 
  mutate(d = ifelse(a + b == 0, 0, ((a/(a+b))*c)+a)) %>% 
  mutate(e = ifelse(a + b == 0, 0, ((b/(a+b))*c)+b)) %>% 
  select(d,e) 
}
```

Let's create some random data to test this:

```r
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(a = rpois(5, 1), b = rpois(5, 2), c = rpois(5, 1))

df
#>   a b c
#> 1 0 0 3
#> 2 2 2 1
#> 3 1 4 1
#> 4 2 2 1
#> 5 3 2 0
```

And we see that we get the expected output:

```
f_calculate_net(df)
#>     d   e
#> 1 0.0 0.0
#> 2 2.5 2.5
#> 3 1.2 4.8
#> 4 2.5 2.5
#> 5 3.0 2.0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Allan, I tried this and I’m still having the same issue, I added further detail to the question about the dataframe and previous code